# Callback not working inside async.foreachof

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm getting my callback from my dao and into my service and in my service i have iterated the list of object to be sent to my dao.

My service code

```
var dao = require('./dao');
var async = require('async');

exports.addUser = function(obj,callback) {
    async.forEachOf(obj,function(value,key,callback){
        dao.addUser(value,function(data){
            callback(data);
        })
    })
}
```

this callback is not going to my control layer

Control layer

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var service = require('./service');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/addPerson',function(req,res){
    var obj = req.body;
    console.log(obj);
    console.log("......",obj.name);
    console.log("......",obj.age);
    service.addUser(obj,function(data) {
        console.log("---->",data);
        res.json(data);
    })
})

var server = app.listen(8080,function(){});
```

i need to send the data back to the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your existing code
1. By referring `callback` you are calling `callback` of the asyn.forEachOf
2. Trying to call ur original callback (which intern does `res.json(data)`). Here you are trying to send multiple response which is not possible.

Try using `async.mapValues` instead

```
exports.addUser = function(obj,callback) {
    async.mapValues(obj,function(value,key,cb){
        dao.addUser(value,function(data){
            cb(null, data);
        })
        }, function(err, result) {
            // result is now a map of results for each key
           callback(result);
      });
}
```

Comment: Muthukumar migavum nandri, i guess you are tamil, anyways! Thank you, so very much dude, you just saved my ass!!!!!!!

Comment: bro can i know why i cant use foreach instead of mapvalues?

Comment: foreach does not return the result of each execution, but mapvalues does.

Comment: why cb(null,data) and not cb(data)

Comment: cb(null, data) corresponds to function(err, result) . So if you catch any errors while adding user, you can pass the error in place of null. More info https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapValues

Comment: if i take out the null, its sending nothing!

Comment: why do you want to remove the error parameter `null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160681/discussion-between-grijan-and-muthukumar).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807737/iterating-objects-as-array-of-objects-sent-through-postman-tool-and-saving-in-db?noredirect=1#comment82576806_47807737   bro i need your help to slove this, take a look on the link pls